# Can I read FDX-B RFID using Android smartphone?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tags, rfid

My pet have ISO 11784/5 FDX-B tag and theoretically, it's an RFID tag, but can I read this tag using my Android smartphone? Which properties shoud I use in my custome app to read this tag?

Comment: The smartphone supports **[13.56Mhz ISO/IEC14443 (at most +ISO/IEC18092)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_communication)**, and it is not possible to access your desired **[ISO/IEC11784/5 124-139KHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_11784_and_ISO_11785)** in terms of hardware. Therefore there will be no software support. It could be a handheld terminal with industrial support, etc. Please look for such products and SDKs.

Comment: @kunif, thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFC (13,56 Mhz) is a subset of RFID and the FDX-B uses 134,2 kHz, so those are not compatible.

But there are cheap 125 kHz RFID readers available (around 12€), which can read the tag. Here is a tutorial, that shows how you could connect it to an Arduino: https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-and-RFID-from-seeedstudio/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.